# Windows 7 virtual machine additions for Linux

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualization

https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf12642f-77dc-4d45-ae4e-e1b05e0a2674

Is the link above, "Virtual Machine Additions for Linux", compatible with Windows 7?  There is no mention of it, but maybe it is?

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser.com?

Comment: I think you've missed the point. The VM additions are for the CLIENT machine, Linux in this case, and have absolutely nothing to do with the host OS, which I'm guessing is Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how your question is tagged, it appears that you are trying to run a Linux guest OS on a Windows 7 computer using Virtual PC.  In my experience, one is usually better off using a non-Microsoft hypervisor when running a non-Microsoft guest OS.

Here are some of the most common options for a Windows 7 host:

1. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is free for personal use.
2. [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) is the free version of VMware Workstation; it allows you to create Linux VMs, but lacks "advanced" features like snapshots.
3. [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) is a commercially licensed option.

All of the above have current, fully supported guest additions for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

They're compatible with Virtual Server 2005, which is can work on Windows 7. Shouldn't be a problem.